# Using SUM within a CASE

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a simple task of adding 1 to the total amount if a condition is met.

So if COLUMN_B contains the value 1 (true) then add 1 to the Total_Amount columnm

In my select statement i have:
`CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 1 THEN SUM(COLUMN_A + 1) ELSE COLUMN_A END AS Total_Amount`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Tag the question with the database that you use and post the full query code because the solution to your problem depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 1 THEN COLUMN_A + 1 ELSE COLUMN_A END) AS Total_Amount
```

Comment: also instead of colum_A i would use coalesce(Column_A,0) to handle the cases when the column contains a null value, because null + 1 is still null

Comment: I re-read your question and unfortunately  my version sums 1 for each row that has COLUMN_B=1. The initial question does not make a lot of sense because you cannot both have a row condition (COLUMN_B =1) and expect to affect an aggregate (SUM) that uses multiple rows.

Comment: if the suggestions here do not work, and you still struggle to get the right result, I would suggest providing a table structure,sample data and expected answer. Because I think you might need to use analytical functions in order to achieve the desired result.
https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` is an *aggregate* function - it's intended to operate across the dataset of the results, CASE is operating on a per row level.

If you want to display column_a + 1 where column_b has the value you want:

```
CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 1 THEN (COLUMN_A + 1) ELSE COLUMN_A END AS Total_Amount
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you for example and clear reason for the answer!

Comment: @marjfh67 my answer here assumes that column_a already contains the total amount value BTW, and that the column_b logic is intended to increase that total by one - if you're acutally aiming to sum all the values of column_a to get a total it would be different and you'd want to do what GabrielDurac's answer suggests.

Comment: your's is fine, as COLUMN_B is essentially just a column for a tick box (1 selected by the user, NULL not selected). So just need COLUMN_A (which is the total of the products and add 1 to it if they select the tick box).

I assume it doesnt matter if i use brackets or not? I.e. CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 1 THEN (COLUMN_A + 1) ELSE COLUMN_A END AS Total_Amount is the same as CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 1 THEN COLUMN_A + 1 ELSE COLUMN_A END AS Total_Amount

Comment: @marjfh67 yeah it will work with or without the brackets around the `COLUMN_A + 1` - just a matter of personal style :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are actually using `SUM()` then the logic would be:

```
(CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 1 THEN SUM(COLUMN_A) + 1
      ELSE SUM(COLUMN_A)
 END) AS Total_Amount
```